# What is the status of Eunuchs now in the Church and also in the world to come?

Tags: protestantism, heaven, ecclesiology, gender

Eunuchs, who are considered to be the third gender, are also human beings. Some eunuchs are made by other human beings, particularly in the ancient times. Some people voluntarily become eunuchs as an expression of their devotion to their faith or religion. However, some people are born eunuchs from their mothers' wombs [Matt.19:12]. These are obviously created by God Himself.

What is the protestant Christianity's position on the status of Eunuchs in the church? What is the protestant Christianity theological understanding with regard to the status and pleasures Eunuchs get in Heaven if they are faithful believers in this life?

Comment: I don't think that scripture teaches, in any verse I know of, that eunuchs are a 'third gender'. You would need to support that theory with evidence. But I did cancel the down-vote as I did not think it to be deserved for that cause alone. My own view is that scripture presents eunuchs as a sub-set of male. In the world to come, the redeemed 'neither marry nor are given in marriage'. And . . .  all are one, in Christ Jesus. No more is said.

Comment: In Mattew 19:12 Jesus did mention "For there are Eunuchs who were born that way from their mother's womb." This seems to suggest that the Eunuchs belong neither to the male gender nor female gender. I may be wrong in understanding like that. I would appreciate more clarity for a different understanding of the verse.

Comment: I wonder if the question might better be asked on Biblical Hermeneutics so that we can pick up on the original word [Strong 2135](https://biblehub.com/greek/2135.htm)(translated into English as 'eunuch'). I can see what you are looking for. It is a sensitive area and not one to be muddled.

Comment: I am not concerned about Eunuchs gender, but their status in the church and in the world to come. As you have rightly pointed out in the world to come they will also be like angels without the need to participate in any biological needs or functions.

Comment: Yes. I notice that Jesus does _not_ say _... like the angels, neither male nor female_. Rather, Jesus relates the whole matter to marriage, not to gender. Male-ness, female-ness and eunuch-ness, therefore, I would (personally) view as a matter of human union and human procreation. [And, therefore, irrelevant in the world to come.]

Comment: Not even in English does "eunuch" equate or imply being neither male nor female. Some eunuchs may be intersex, some may self-identify as non-binary or third gender, but it is not a valid generalisation. As to the question, I'm curious why you think being either born a eunuch or made one later in life would have any relevance to a person's status in the church or to their salvation?

Comment: Well, Nigel has pointed out from the Bible about the status of Eunuchs in the life to come. But I would like to know from protestant Christians, will there be any special limitations or not as far as the status of all those who are categorised as Eunuchs is concerned in the life and activities of believers within the church? This is because even males and females have different roles and responsibilities in the Bible as some protestant groups understand.

Comment: There is nothing to suggest that an eunuch would be treated any differently to any other male. Daniel might well have been a eunuch. For all we know, Paul might have been one. But these personal details are known only to those individuals. Nor does anyone need to know these details. And as far as my own knowledge of such things has (thus far) progressed, there is never (to my own limited knowledge) an occasion in which the matter is so ambiguous that one's place in the assembly (as to function) would be indeterminate. But this is an extremely sensitive area and requires caution.